# Nuxt Universal Static is not routing pages

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using `Nuxt.js` in `Universal` mode and I can run `npm run dev` ok which displays all of my pages.

If I then use `npm run build` and then `npm run start` this works fine as it fires up node server and serves the pages.

However if I use `npm run build` which builds the page it also generates all of my static files but if I just browse to my dist folder to fire up a static `npm http server` using `serve -s dist` the pages get served but all my routes are broken.

How can I view and serve my static files?

I also did a fresh install of the `Nuxt` and ran the same commands and everything works correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have built my project from scratch, generated and tested `dist` with "Web Server for Chrome" localhosting. Works perfectly fine for me tho. That would be likely rely on your project structure and dependencies

I assume you followed the routing guide https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/

1) tried `npm cache clean` and `npm install` again?

2) use `npm run generate` to get `/dist` folder and try test localhosting other than `npm http server`?

Comment: Ok...How awesome is chrome web server? It works through here on Chrome Web Server so I tried 1 and to and this works correctly.

Comment: pretty much as my daily tool for quick static files viewing/prototyping. Been friendly with it for about 4 years. As i hear `npm http` sometimes might have issue so i just go with stable ones.